# Prove: $\text{arcsinh}(x)>\ln(1+x),\; x>-1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, inequality

Prove:

$$\text{arcsinh}(x)>\ln(1+x),\; x>-1$$

I tried to prove that $f'(x)>0$ and then $f(x)$ is increasing, but I couldn't conclude it. Is there another way to prove this?

Comment: Hint: Can you show that $x>\sinh\ln(1+x)$? The RHS is quite simple, if you try to write it down...

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)=\mathrm{ln}\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)$ by definition. Furthermore, for $x>-1$:
$$\sqrt{1+x^2}\ \geq \ 1 \implies x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\ \geq \ x+1 \implies \mathrm{ln}\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)\ \geq\ \mathrm{ln}\left(1+x\right),$$
where the last step follows from monotonicity of $\mathrm{ln}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{1+x^2}\ge 1$ for *all* $x$.

Comment: I'd say that is irrelevant to the question or the answer...